# MQTT message published, for new device not registered with TB gateway, errors in logs

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, thingsboard

Windows 10 setup :

1. Thingsboard server running as local service on windows

   Thingsboard.yml mqtt parameters

   ```
    MQTT server parameters
       mqtt:
         bind_address: "${MQTT_BIND_ADDRESS:0.0.0.0}"
         bind_port: "${MQTT_BIND_PORT:1883}"
         adaptor: "${MQTT_ADAPTOR_NAME:JsonMqttAdaptor}"
         timeout: "${MQTT_TIMEOUT:10000}"
   ```
2. Thingsboard gateway service running as local service on windows

> ```
> > tb-gateway.yml mqtt parameters
> >     mqtt:
> >       enabled: true
> >       configuration: mqtt-config.json
> ```

configuration file of mqtt is set by default,below.

```
mqtt-config.json mqtt parameters
 "brokers": [
    {
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 1883,
      "ssl": false,
      "retryInterval": 3000,
      "credentials": {
        "type": "anonymous"
      },
```

These are the only two services running on my laptop, I published a mqtt message as follows, per docs :

```
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -p 1883 -u "XXXXXXXX" -t "sensors" -m '{"serialNumber":"TB-GW-SN-001","model":"TB-GW-T1000","temperature":35.2}'
```

I see errors in both the logs.

```
thingsboard.log

2018-01-10 20:14:56,174 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-11] INFO  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [mqtt815] Processing connect msg for client: efd91958-ba8f-480a-9a56-ad9d5588c8c7!
2018-01-10 20:14:56,177 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-12] INFO  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [127.0.0.1:51192] Invalid message received
2018-01-10 20:14:59,183 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-1] INFO  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [mqtt817] Processing connect msg for client: efd91958-ba8f-480a-9a56-ad9d5588c8c7!
2018-01-10 20:14:59,188 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-2] INFO  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [127.0.0.1:51194] Invalid message received
2018-01-10 20:15:02,193 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-3] INFO  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [mqtt819] Processing connect msg for client: efd91958-ba8f-480a-9a56-ad9d5588c8c7!
2018-01-10 20:15:02,197 [nioEventLoopGroup-6-4] INFO  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [127.0.0.1:51196] Invalid message received
```

error in thingsboard gateway is strange, rather.

```
tb-gateway.log

2018-01-10 20:14:59,191 [main] WARN  o.t.g.e.m.client.MqttBrokerMonitor - [localhost:1883] MQTT broker connection failed!
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: Connection lost
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:164)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:116)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
2018-01-10 20:15:02,198 [main] WARN  o.t.g.e.m.client.MqttBrokerMonitor - [localhost:1883] MQTT broker connection failed!
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: Connection lost
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:164)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:116)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

What am I doing wrong? I have mosquitto installed locally, hence used the mosquitto_pub tool to publish the messages.

Any clues, folks?

Comment: Are you sure the access token of the gateway is correctly specified in the config and the device is marked as a gateway? Not clear why you use the same port (1883) in both mqtt config and general config. Mqtt config should point to your mosquitto port and general gateway config should point to TB port.

Comment: Do i need to have mosquitto running in background? I thought TB will act as  MQTT broker. lets say, mosquitto runs on port 1882. I publish a payload on 1882 using mosquitto_pub. TB-gateway should listen on mosquitto port(which is 1882, as in mqtt-config.json)  and in turn publish the payload on 1883, for TB server. This means, mosquitto daemon should be running in 1882, in background. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

All is well.

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/3203737/andrew pointed out, I wasnt running mosquitto and the ports were the same. I cleaned up the mess and the devices were registered perfectly using TB-gateway, in the dashboard.